# Conversion methods for QJsonValue always return their default value

Tags: qt, qt5, qjson

I am trying to convert QJsonValues into their correct data types, but the conversion always ends up returning their default value.

For example, I have the following JSON object:

```
{
    "val1": 99,
    "val2": true,
    "val3": "test"
}
```

I'm getting these values with:

```
QJsonValue val1 = jsonObj.value("val1");
QJsonValue val2 = jsonObj.value("val2");
QJsonValue val3 = jsonObj.value("val3");
```

Now, if I check these QJsonValues in the Debug view, they all have their correct value and data types.

I'm seeing...

- **val1** as **99 - QJsonValue(Number)**
- **val2** as **true - QJsonValue(Bool)**
- **val3** as **"test" - QJsonValue(String)**

I now do the following:

```
int valInt1 = val1.toInt();
bool valBool2 = val2.toBool();
QString valString3 = val3.toString();
```

This will give me **0** for **valInt1**, **false** for **valBool2** and **"test"** for **valString3**.
For some reason, toString() seems to be working correctly, but the other conversion methods all result in their default value.

With **val1** I can do the following to make it work:

```
int valInt1 = val1.toString().toInt();
```

But that is not an option for bool values.

Does anyone know how I could solve this problem? I believe I'm doing everything right here. Not sure what the issue might be and the documentation does things exactly how I would do them, but the conversions always return default values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem for now by converting the JsonObject to a QVariantMap and ignoring the QJsonValues. They are either bugged or I do not understand how they work.

```
QVariantMap map = jsonObj.toVariantMap();

int valInt1 = map.value("val1").toInt();
bool valBool2 = map.value("val2").toBool();
QString valString3 = map.value("val3").toString();
```